Optimal stopping problems in finite time
I'm recently learning optimal stopping problems from Oksendal chapter 10 (I am familiar with the early chapters of the book: 2-5, 7-8). After reading through the chapter on optimal stopping, I realised that the whole chapter talks about infinite horizon optimal stopping problems. I'm working on a project with similar problems as those in the book, but in finite time.
For example, the optimal stopping problem $g^*(x)=\sup_\tau \mathbb{E}^x\left(B^2_\tau\right)$ (exercise 10.1(a) in the book) does not have an optimal stopping time $\tau^*$ and $g^*(x)=\infty$. Intuitively this is because the Brownian motion is unbounded and reaches every number with probability 1, so it is never optimal to stop. However, the problem relevant to me is, what happens when we restrict to some finite time interval $[0,T]$? Let's say that the payoff from not stopping in $[0,T]$ is $0$, then surely an optimal stopping time exists? I would like some references on solving these types of problems.
I also realise that this is equivalent to defining the payoff function $g$ as $g(t, \xi)=\xi^2 \mathbf{1}_{t\leq T}$, essentially forcing the payoff to be zero if stopping after $T$. However, this makes the function $g$ discontinuous, and Oksendal only considers continuous $g$, and makes no reference in the book on how to deal with discontinuous payoff functions.
The book does mention that some of the assumptions on $g$ can be replaced by alternative conditions, for example $g$ must be bounded below can be replaced by the assumption $\{g^-_\tau\}$ is uniformly integrable, thereby allowing problems such as Ex10.15 to be solved, but does not go in detail on why this works. Is there a similar way to deal with discontinuous $g$? Any references, or comments, are highly appreciated!
